# How to characterize unknown perturbations in practice ? FFT analysis?

Tags: fft, signal-analysis, frequency-spectrum, frequency-response

I want to analyze the motion `X(t)` of a very flexible structure, which is excited/forced by unknown perturbations, in order to characterize this perturbations.

Hence, I plan to record the motion at one point of the structure thanks to a sensor, and then to analyze the results with a FFT to find the greatest contributions : the dominant frequencies and the corresponding magnitude.

Let say I keep the first three dominant peeks and let say the perturbation could be approximate by a sum of three sinusoids

```
X_per(t) = A0 + A1 * sin(w1*t) + A2 * sin(w2*t) + A3 * sin(w3*t)
```

As my structure is very flexible, I believe that the structure will follow the perturbation(the frequencies of oscillation of the structure should be same as forcing frequencies)

Does it mean that we can assume the FFT results match with the AO, A1, A2, A3, w1, w2, w3 coefficients of the forced excitation ?

Is this assumption correct ?
Is it the correct way to use FFT ?

I believe that if we had an impulse excitation, the first peak in the FFT would be the natural frequency of the structure. Am I correct ?

Thanks

Comment: "the structure will follow the perturbation" and "my structure is very flexible"  seems a direct contradiction to me. The first one implies that all points of the structure move the same way, i.e. it's rigid which is the exact opposite of "flexible". If the  structure is flexing, than all points move differently and so you have a lot of different transfer function from the perturbation to each individual location on the structure.

Comment: In addition to Hilmar's good comment, it seems feasible to me that your structure could be non-linear, perhaps at stronger input excitation levels in which case a single tone will create higher harmonics. If your sampling rate isn't high enough to capture all the harmonics they will fold in (so you'll see this in practice if that is occurring, plus you can test with a single tone to make it easier). I am not a mechanical engineer so not posting in confidence below but concur with your assumptions and thoughts other than being aware of non-linearities.

Comment: Ok I am not sure to understand correctly your answers, so I will try to clear my explanation.
My structure is like a flag, bounded at one edge. 
A small perturbation will easily have chance to deform my structure, and I believe that while it is fluttering, every points of the flag won't have the exact same motion. (where it is clamped it won't move at all)
That what I mean by, "the structure will follow the perturbation". I may should say "the structure will easily respond /  connect to this perturbation".

Comment: Moreover, there is a chance that this structure has a chance to have large deformation, that's what I mean by "very flexible"